# I want to put short code on the right hand side of my screen?

Tags: php, html

I would like to put a simple short code on the right hand side of my screen.

On the left I would like:

```
<hr> <?php echo do_shortcode('[smoothslider]'):?> <hr>
```

and on the right I would like:

```
<hr> <?php echo do_shortcode('[easysubscribe]'):?> <hr>
```

How do I do this? Currently they just go on top of each other.

Comment: Use <div> tag with a unique id value for all your shortcode, then use CSS for position them where you want. Using for example CSS rules { position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0; } for left side and { position:absolute; top: 0; right: 0; } for right side.

Answer (score 1):

use `float:right` to place content to right side of window and `float:left` for left side.

**CSS**

```
.leftalign{
     top : 0;
     float: left;
}

.rightalign{
     top : 0;
     float: right;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<hr><div class='leftalign'> <?php echo do_shortcode('[smoothslider]'):?> </div>
<div class='rightalign'> <?php echo do_shortcode('[easysubscribe]'):?> </div>
```

Here is **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YD5L2/)**